# kubelet is down in prometheus target

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have installed prometheus-operator using helm. It was all working fine but then I changed worker group to t2.large.

Now I don't see anything on grafana dashboard and in prometheus target I am getting

```
Get http://10.10.11.207:10255/metrics/cadvisor: dial tcp 10.10.11.207:10255: connect: connection refused
```

For endpoint 
http://10.10.11.207:10255/metrics/cadvisor
and 
http://10.10.11.207:10255/metrics

Any suggestion how can I fix it?

Comment: Was the 10.10.11.207 related to a node beloging to the removed worker group?

Answer (score 0):

These days cAdvisor is coming as an embedded service with Kubelet. so, ssh to the cluster nodes and restart your kubelet service using

```
  systemctl restart kubelet
```